# Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Statement.executeUpdate() cannot be called with a statement that returns a ResultSet

Tags: java, jpa

Я повторяю пример по JPA из книги, и у меня не получается в тесте добавить данные из файла, который является sql-скриптом, во встроенную базу данных. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?
У меня в проекте имеются следующие файлы.
Сущность Book:

```
package org.example;

import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "findAllBooks", query = "SELECT b FROM Book b"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "findBookH2G2", query = "SELECT b FROM Book b WHERE b.title ='H2G2'")
})
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private Float price;
    private String description;
    private String isbn;
    private Integer nbOfPage;
    private Boolean illustrations;

    public Book() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public Integer getNbOfPage() {
        return nbOfPage;
    }

    public void setNbOfPage(Integer nbOfPage) {
        this.nbOfPage = nbOfPage;
    }

    public Boolean getIllustrations() {
        return illustrations;
    }

    public void setIllustrations(Boolean illustrations) {
        this.illustrations = illustrations;
    }
}
```

Файл persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="chapter04TestPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>org.example.Book</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="metadata"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-source" value="metadata"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:memory:chapter04DB;create=true"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="META-INF/insert.sql"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Скрипт insert.sql:

```
INSERT INTO BOOK(ID, TITLE, DESCRIPTION, ILLUSTRATIONS, ISBN, NBOFPAGE, PRICE)
values (1010, 'The Lord of the Rings', 'One ring to rule them all', 0, '9012-3456', 222, 23)
```

Файл с тестом:

```
package org.example;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;


public class AppTest {
    private static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("chapter04TestPU");
    private EntityManager em;

    @Before
    public void initEntityManager() throws Exception {
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    @After
    public void closeEntityManager() throws Exception {
        if (em != null) em.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldFindBook() throws Exception {
        Book book = em.find(Book.class, 1010L);
//        assertEquals("The Lord of the Rings", book.getTitle());
    }
}
```

POM.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1-b11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.14.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Стек ошибки:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_281/bin/java -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 -javaagent:/home/galina/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/203.7148.57/lib/idea_rt.jar=44847:/home/galina/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/203.7148.57/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/galina/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/203.7148.57/lib/idea_rt.jar:/home/galina/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/203.7148.57/plugins/junit/lib/junit5-rt.jar:/home/galina/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/203.7148.57/plugins/junit/lib/junit-rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_281/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_281/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_281/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_281/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_281/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_281/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_281/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_281/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_281/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_281/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_281/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_281/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_281/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_281/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_281/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_281/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_281/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_281/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_281/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_281/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_281/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/galina/Примеры проектов/example/target/test-classes:/home/galina/Примеры проектов/example/target/classes:/home/galina/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa/2.7.7/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa-2.7.7.jar:/home/galina/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/persistence/jakarta.persistence/2.2.3/jakarta.persistence-2.2.3.jar:/home/galina/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.asm/2.7.7/org.eclipse.persistence.asm-2.7.7.jar:/home/galina/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.antlr/2.7.7/org.eclipse.persistence.antlr-2.7.7.jar:/home/galina/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql/2.7.7/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql-2.7.7.jar:/home/galina/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.core/2.7.7/org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.7.7.jar:/home/galina/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/javax.el/3.0.1-b11/javax.el-3.0.1-b11.jar:/home/galina/.m2/repository/org/apache/derby/derby/10.14.2.0/derby-10.14.2.0.jar:/home/galina/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar:/home/galina/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit4 org.example.AppTest,shouldFindBook
[EL Info]: 2021-09-02 12:17:00.431--ServerSession(1764696127)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d
[EL Warning]: 2021-09-02 12:17:02.43--ServerSession(1764696127)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'SEQUENCE' does not exist.
Error Code: 30000
Call: DELETE FROM SEQUENCE WHERE SEQ_NAME = 'SEQ_GEN'
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="DELETE FROM SEQUENCE WHERE SEQ_NAME = 'SEQ_GEN'")
[EL Warning]: 2021-09-02 12:17:02.661--ServerSession(1764696127)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 78.
Error Code: 30000
Call: INSERT INTO BOOK(ID, TITLE, DESCRIPTION, ILLUSTRATIONS, ISBN, NBOFPAGE, PRICE)
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="INSERT INTO BOOK(ID, TITLE, DESCRIPTION, ILLUSTRATIONS, ISBN, NBOFPAGE, PRICE)")
[EL Warning]: 2021-09-02 12:17:02.672--ServerSession(1764696127)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Statement.executeUpdate() cannot be called with a statement that returns a ResultSet.
Error Code: 30000
Call: values (1010, 'The Lord of the Rings', 'One ring to rule them all', 0, '9012-3456', 222, 23)
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="values (1010, 'The Lord of the Rings', 'One ring to rule them all', 0, '9012-3456', 222, 23)")

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Похоже, что не поддерживаются многострочные запросы. Так же, похоже, нужно ставить точку с запятой в конце запроса. Я бы с этого начал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Было 2 ошибки:

1. в блоке persistence-unit не хватало строчки
   `<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>`
2. в файле со скриптом у меня был разрыв строки